# Stormpath admin only login android studio

Tags: android-studio, stormpath

I am trying to create an admin only login on android studio using storm path. I am able to login any account right now, but I want to limit the people who can login based on who is in the Admin group in strompath.

```
                StormpathCallback<Void> loginCallback = new StormpathCallback<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        Stormpath.getAccessToken();
                        finish();
                        startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, (Class) redirectActivity));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(StormpathError error) {
                        showAlert();
                       // finish();
                        //startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, (Class) redirectActivity));

                    }
                };
```

Comment: Are you using a Stormpath SDK? Or making API calls manually?

Comment: I have imported the storm path sdk and have been using that.

Comment: Can you share the code you're using to log the user in?

Comment: I added the code. If you need anything else let me know.